# How to manually change UICollectionView height in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm hiding rows that are completed in a collectionView.
I call `cell.hidden = isCellHidden` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` when needed.

After I hide 10 rows there is plenty of empty space left and I'd like to trim down the size of the collectionView to only fit the rows that are not hidden.

The collectionView's design is kind of like a tableView. 
I know with the tableView all I had to do to achieve this is set:

```
func section1VisibilityButton(sender: UIButton){
    isCellHidden = !isCellHidden
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.tableView.contentSize.height = CGFloat(500)
}
```

with a collectionView when I try this it will resize it correctly but as soon as I try to scroll down it resizes itself back to the original height including the cells hidden (the cells layer is still hidden but there's tons of empty space bellow the last visible row as if they were visible)

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, there are two options to change the frame of your collectionView/tableView.

1. If you are using **autolayout**, you need to create `IBOutlet of bottom constraint` or `IBOutlet of constant height constraint` of your `tableView` (anyone of these constraints, which you are using).
2. After `reload tableView` data you need to **update constraint** by calculating its `height`.

Suppose you are **using** `constant height constraint` and your calculated `height` is `150`(e.g. 3 rows and 50 height of each row).

```
constraintTableViewHeight.constant = 150;//this will change height

self.view.layoutIfneed(); // this will apply updated constraints to whole view
```

3. If you are **not using autolayout**, you can manually change the height by changing **tableView.frame** property.

Comment: thanks for replying but it looks like your suggestion doesn't take into account that the collectionView is bigger than the size of the screen, therefore you need to scroll down to get to the bottom.
The constraint frame can only be as big as your iPhone screen and that's not what I need. 
If I delete all constraints (disabling auto layout) I have the same exact result as before when I was setting the frame

Comment: -> With this line "constraintTableViewHeight.constant = 150;//this will change height", I have just given the Hint about how you can change height of any view


->you need to set "if condition" with your "maximumAllowedHeight" value

Comment: Hm, never mind, I see what you are saying. I still don't think that's a good way of doing this because the scroll indicator looks very weird with this method and it looks like I need to do everything with negative numbers. This achieves the same result as collectionView.contentInset would do...

Comment: contentInset will change only change the position of content of collectionView/tableView, it will not change the actual position/frame of your view.